# BitmapFrame - No imaging component suitable to complete this operation was found

Tags: c#, wpf

This is NOT the same as my previous question [same error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251250/no-imaging-component-suitable-to-complete-this-operation-was-found-when-using)

This is the url `https://www.walgreens.com/images/adaptive/share/images/logos/Mobile_Logo_DD.png` [wallgreens](https://www.walgreens.com/images/adaptive/share/images/logos/Mobile_Logo_DD.png) (this is an example of several which cause the same exception.

I monitor the session with fiddler and it correctly sees the image (it was not compressed). Maybe of interest is `Content-Type: image\webp` ?

The stream I am using is at the beginning.

In addition to the exception "No imagining component..." there is also an inner exception of "The Component cannot be found"

I am using the following to download the icon

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = GetHttpWebResponse(faviconUrl))
{
    if (response?.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        using (Stream stream = GetSeekableStream(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            imageSource = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously WPF does not support `image/webp`.

Comment: seems like I can change the UserAgent in the request to prevent the server from sending webp images.

Comment: Or try to set the [Accept](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.accept.aspx) property